# Disable Access-Control-Allow-Origin in ASP.Net and ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms, cors, xss

We just had an external pen test and all of our sites are coming back with a low warning stating that we allow cross site scripting.
I don't think this is actually the case since we had to specifically allow it on one page on one specific site for that one to work.

The report shows that when calling our URL's a header for Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to *.
Using Postman I can get that same result.

[image: PostMan Screenshot]

This is returning the same result from both ASP.Net web forms applications as well as new ASP.Net 6 Razor page apps.
Is there any way to have this header removed?
Maybe something in IIS?

Comment: How did you get the response headers,I  setted cros in my .net core project but didn't get the response headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of it you have to list all the origins that are allowed to send the requests to your endpoint. If you are running ASP.NET Core application then you have to configure the CORS middleware like this:

```cs
// Startup.ConfigureServices() method

// For example only, put these values in the appsettings.json so they could be overridden if you need it
var corsAllowAnyOrigin = false;
var corsAllowOrigins = new string[]{ "https://*.contoso.com", "https://api.contoso.com" };

// Configuring CORS module
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        builder =>
        {
            if (apiConfiguration.CorsAllowAnyOrigin)
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            }
            else
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(apiConfiguration.CorsAllowOrigins);
            }

            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});
```

For your Web Forms application you can install IIS CORS module and configure it  in the `web.config` file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true">
      <add origin="*" allowed="false"/>
      <add origin="https://*.contoso.com" allowCredentials="false" />
      <add origin="https://api.contoso.com" allowCredentials="true" />
    </cors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So what if you don't want any external site to have CORS access?
Would you simply just not do the builder.WithOrigins() at all?

Comment: If you don't want to let any other origin send requests to your server then you can disable CORS middleware by removing mentions of Cors from both `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods.

Comment: Alexey,
We do not have any CORS items in the ConfigureServices or Configure methods but still show the * when calling the the site.
We tried to add just one site using the sample above, but it still shows *.
I'm starting to believe that this is not coming from our application, but rather the Azure App Gateway that sits in front of the website.